# What's the problem with groves?

Tags: exegesis, bible-translation, exodus, deuteronomy, 2-kings

In Exodus 34:13, Deuteronomy 7:5, Deuteronomy 12:3, God states laws against idolatry, and God says to cut down or burn groves:

> **Exodus 34:13 KJV**
>   But ye shall destroy their altars, break their
>   images, and **cut down their groves**:
>
> **Deuteronomy 7:5 KJV**
>   But thus shall ye deal with them; ye shall
>   destroy their altars, and break down their images, and **cut down their
>   groves**, and burn their graven images with fire.
>
> **Deuteronomy 12:3 KJV**
>   And ye shall overthrow their altars, and break
>   their pillars, and **burn their groves** with fire; and ye shall hew down
>   the graven images of their gods, and destroy the names of them out of
>   that place.

Some kings, fighting against idolatry, accomplished that commandment, like Hezekiah
:

> **2 Kings 18:4 KJV**
>   He removed the high places, and brake the images,
>   and **cut down the groves**, and brake in pieces the brasen serpent that
>   Moses had made: for unto those days the children of Israel did burn
>   incense to it: and he called it Nehushtan.

In my native language (portuguese), "grove" is translated as a "forest". So I thought: What's the problem with some trees? What's related to idolatry on groves?

Using **strong**, the "grove" word is **H842** (happy; asherah (or Astarte) a Phoenician goddess; also an image of the same). God was fighting the idolatry about that goddess?

Comment: Per my answer below, I think it absolutely /does/ mean a grove of trees. Not any old grove, of course.... Presumably modern translations avoid the word because they don't expect their audience to be familiar with classical drama. Earlier translations may have assumed this familiarity among the literate.

Comment: Read also: Ben Hur at the [Grove of Daphne](http://books.google.com/books?id=w4EZAAAAYAAJ&lpg=PA202&ots=cCfT1d19J7&dq=ben%20hur%20grove&pg=PA202#v=onepage&q&f=false)

Comment: The [***asherah poles***](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asherah_pole) are still used in voodoo today. its called a ["***poteau mitan***”](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potomitan) (***potomitan***) or middle pole in French. It is where the serpents and the spirits come through from hell like a portal.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs at [hermeneutics.se], but is too old to be migrated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Sacred groves](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sacred_grove) are a common feature of ancient pagan religion.

A particularly accessible Western example might be *Oedipus at Colonus*, which is the middle play in the Theban cycle of Sophocles (following *Oedipus Rex* and preceding *Antigone*).

A great deal of the action in *Oedipus at Colonus* takes place in a grove outside Colonus that is consecrated to the "Erinyes" (goddesses of vengeance).

It's also not uncommon in the legends of early-medieval Western saints for the saint to cut down a sacred tree in the presence of pagan clerics and dignitaries, in a sort of recapitulation of 1 Kings 18 -- e.g., [Boniface and the Donar Oak](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Donar_Oak).

Answer (score 4):

Yes.  The original word *Asherah* referred to shrines to a fertility goddess, not to forests, groves, or trees in general.  There's nothing wrong with having trees around, of course; this is just another example of God's repeated warnings against idolatry.  Asherah was the consort of Baal, whose worshipers were always a thorn in the side of Israel, and the two were often worshiped together as male and female aspects of fertility worship.  See [Judges 6](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Judges%206:25-32&version=KJV) for one example.  And as the verses you cite show, cutting down *asherah* is always found in the context of doing away with idols and idol-worship.